excel formula - highlight repeated value
Datasheet

Hi,
I´d like to find out what excel formula uses if I need to find every fifth number 4 in same column. And to highlight it with some specific text in a note.
The excel example in the attachment.
I tried something like:
=IF(MOD(COUNTIF(E$3:E3,4),5)=0,"Match","")
Of course, it doesn´t make a full sense and it is failing in the case if number 4 does not appear again after "match"...

Your formula is working, only a check needs that the corresponding cell contains value 4 (or tested)
=IF(AND(MOD(COUNTIF(A$3:A3,4),5)=0,A3=4),"Match","")
With the AND function the conditions will be only TRUE if cell contains the value 4.

As Blackcat commented, your formula works after adding check for E3 = 4

If you have Excel for Microsoft 365, here's way:

Enter this dynamic array formula in I3 (change the data range E3:H30 to match yours):

=LET(data, E3:H30,
match_col, LAMBDA(acc,col, HSTACK(acc,
  MAP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)), LAMBDA(r,
    IF(
      AND(
          INDEX(data, r, col) = 4,
          MOD(COUNTIF(INDEX(data, 1, col):INDEX(data, r, col), 4), 5) = 0
      ), "Match", ""))))),
DROP(REDUCE("", SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data)), match_col), , 1))


Here, using REDUCE we process each column with MAP processing the rows in each column
We then use the Match cells for conditional formatting with I3 = "Match"
Since the main formula is in a single cell it will be easier to maintain.



Hello another way if i understand correct your reqyuest is by using countifs + mod function in this way and then use this formula in conditional formatting:
=IF(IFERROR(MOD(IF(A2=4,COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2),""),5),"")=0,TRUE,FALSE)


Hope it helps.

The solution for this task:

Pay attention at correct addressing in the formatting formula.
J2 formula:
=LET(r,$H$2:$H$23,MOD(MATCH(ROW(r),FILTER(SEQUENCE(ROWS(r),1,ROW(r)),r=4,0),0),5)=0)

You can use the next formula directly as the conditional formatting formula:
=AND(MOD(COUNTIF(L$2:L2,4),5)=0,L2=4)


